# PHP PDO retrieves duplicate data

Tags: php

I have this situation with PHP (PDO);

I'm implementing a method that retrieves data from MySql and does it well, but the problem is that duplicate data recovered as key bone as no value but other data appends more, leave the script and images for more detail;

Data.php

```
    //read
    public function getData() {
    $statement = $this->db->prepare("select Id,Company_Name,Contact_Name,Contact_Title,Address from contact_details LIMIT 3;");
    $statement->execute();
    if ($statement->rowCount() > 0) {
        $value = $statement->fetchAll();
        return $value;
    }
}
```

variable inspection

[image]

json duplicate

[image]

**expected result**

```
Data: [{"Id":"1","Company_Name":"Romero y tomillo","Contact_Name":"Alejandra                 Camino","Contact_Title":"Accounting Manager","Address":null}
,{"Id":"2","Company_Name":"Morgenstern Gesundkost","Contact_Name":"Alexander Feuer","Contact_Title":"Marketing Assistant","Address":"Heerstr. 22"}
,{"Id":"3","Company_Name":"Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados","Contact_Name":"Ana Trujillo","Contact_Title":"Owner","Address":null}]
```

Answer (score 6):

By default PDO uses the PDO::FETCH_BOTH as its fetch result. Meaning that it maps every column to its name and to an 'integer' column name.

Check the fetch_style param= http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

For your expected result you will need to use the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` attribute.
You can or set this as the default FETCH_MODE on the pdo object as follows:

```
$this->db->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Or you can specify it for every fetch cal:

```
$value = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: it works fine, but returns only one object, should to return three objects from the recovery with select

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with that comment. I edited the answer with some code examples

Answer (score 1):

change pdo attribute accoding to requirment. . .

```
 $dbConnection = new PDO( 'pgsql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $database, $username, 
 $password, );

 $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

[set / change PDO attribute more detail here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)